# Finding lines where the occurrence of word happens only after a specific searched word

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

Consider the below set of lines in a file:

File1.csv

```
Apple is red WHERE the column ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID, it can be plucked
Apple is red ON ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID , WHERE it can be plucked
```

I want to look after if ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID occurs only after the word WHERE then only it should print it.

So for the above File it should print only the Line -
Apple is red where the column ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID, it can be plucked

and ignore the second as ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID is not after WHERE.

Please help with the solution I am trying to do a normal grep and with that I am getting both the lines

```
grep ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID
```

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: If `FOOWHEREBAR the column BOBALP_ACCT_PROD_IDSUE` existed in the input should that line be printed or not? Please include substrings, punctuation, regexp metachars, etc. in your sample input/output so we can see how you want them handled. It's always much easier to match lines you want than to not match similar lines you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
grep 'WHERE.*ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID' File1.csv
```

- `WHERE` - Literal match on `WHERE`.
- `.*` - Match on `.` (any character) `*` times (zero or more times)
- `ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID` - Literal match on `ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to look after if ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID occurs only after the word WHERE then only it should print it. ..."*

Use the `-E` switch, to interpret the pattern as an *"[extended regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)"*.

This will assert that if the value contains "*ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID*", it must be preceded by any number of characters, and the text, "*WHERE*".

```bash
grep -E 'WHERE\s+.+\s+ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python should to be

```
import re

pattern = '^(.*)WHERE.*ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID'
text = 'Apple is red WHERE the column ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID, it can be plucked'
finded = re.match(pattern, text)

# this matches the first parenthesis, aka group
finded.group(1)
```

and if `ALP_ACCT_PROD_ID` comes after `where` the match is not valid.